# (Java) Need help summing digits in sets of integers and applying them to a credit card verification algorithm

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have to create a java program that verifies a credit card number based on whether it is a Visa or MasterCard. I am required to read the card number as a single string with spaces in between each set of four digits (xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx). There must be 16 digits. All the digits in the number must be totaled. Then, if sum%10=0, it is a valid Visa. If sum%10=1, it is a valid MasterCard. Any deviation from this results in an invalid message.

My problem is that once I run my current program, I enter the number and the card type, and then the program stops and won't continue. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment4
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String cardNum;
        String typeAnswer;
        char cardType;
        int testSum;
        int modResult;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("\t\t Credit Card Verification");
        System.out.println("\t\t ========================");
        System.out.println("Enter your card number <xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx>: ");
        cardNum = scan.nextLine();

        if(cardNum.length()<19 || cardNum.length()>19)
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect card number. Re-launch the program  and enter a 16-digit card number");
            System.exit(0);
         }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Is your card Visa or MasterCard?");
        typeAnswer = scan.next().toUpperCase();
        cardType = answer.charAt(0);

        String numSet1 = cardNum.substring(0,4);
        String numSet2 = cardNum.substring(5,9);
        String numSet3 = cardNum.substring(10,14);
        String numSet4 = cardNum.substring(15,19);


        int i = Integer.parseInt(numSet1);
        int j = Integer.parseInt(numSet2);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(numSet3);
        int l = Integer.parseInt(numSet4);

        int sum1=0;
        while(i>0)
            {
                sum1 = sum1 + (i%10);
                i = i/10;
            }
        int sum2 = 0;
        while(j>0)
            {
                sum2 = sum2 + (j%10);
                j = j/10;
            }
        int sum3 = 0;
        while(k>0)
            {
                sum3 = sum3+ (k%10);
                k = k/10;
            } 
        int sum4 = 0;
        while(l>0)
            {
               sum4 = sum4 + (l%10);
               j = j/10;
            }


        testSum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4;
        modResult = testSum%10

        if(modResult=0 && cardType=V)
        {
            System.out.println("Valid Visa card.");

        }
        else if (modResult=1 && cardType=M)
            {
                System.out.println("Valid MasterCard.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not a valid " + typeAnswer + " card. Re-launch and try again.");
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth this code compiles?

Answer (score 1):

- `answer` is undefined. It should be `typeAnswer`.
- A semicolon is missing after `modResult = testSum%10`.
- The conditions in `if` statements are wrong:

  - Use `==` operator, not `=` operator, to compare values of primitive types.
  - Use Character literals `'V'` and `'M'` instead of undefined symbols `V` and `M`.
- `l` is not updated in the 4th loop, so it will be an infinite loop if the 4th number is positive. `j = j/10;` should be `l = l/10;`.

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment4
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String cardNum;
        String typeAnswer;
        char cardType;
        int testSum;
        int modResult;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("\t\t Credit Card Verification");
        System.out.println("\t\t ========================");
        System.out.println("Enter your card number <xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx>: ");
        cardNum = scan.nextLine();

        if(cardNum.length()<19 || cardNum.length()>19)
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect card number. Re-launch the program  and enter a 16-digit card number");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Is your card Visa or MasterCard?");
            typeAnswer = scan.next().toUpperCase();
            cardType = typeAnswer.charAt(0);

            String numSet1 = cardNum.substring(0,4);
            String numSet2 = cardNum.substring(5,9);
            String numSet3 = cardNum.substring(10,14);
            String numSet4 = cardNum.substring(15,19);


            int i = Integer.parseInt(numSet1);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(numSet2);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(numSet3);
            int l = Integer.parseInt(numSet4);

            int sum1=0;
            while(i>0)
            {
                sum1 = sum1 + (i%10);
                i = i/10;
            }
            int sum2 = 0;
            while(j>0)
            {
                sum2 = sum2 + (j%10);
                j = j/10;
            }
            int sum3 = 0;
            while(k>0)
            {
                sum3 = sum3+ (k%10);
                k = k/10;
            } 
            int sum4 = 0;
            while(l>0)
            {
               sum4 = sum4 + (l%10);
               l = l/10;
            }


            testSum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4;
            modResult = testSum%10;

            if(modResult==0 && cardType=='V')
            {
                System.out.println("Valid Visa card.");
            }
            else if (modResult==1 && cardType=='M')
            {
                System.out.println("Valid MasterCard.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not a valid " + typeAnswer + " card. Re-launch and try again.");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Note that there are more problems to be fixed in this program. For example, this program accepts `-123 -456 -789 -147` as a valid Visa card.

Answer (score 0):

In the line: `cardType=answer.charAt(0);` You have an error. The variable answer is undefined. It should be `cardType=typeAnswer.charAt(0);`
Next you have created an infinity loop ,i.e. the fourth loop
`while(l>0)
            {
               sum4 = sum4 + (l%10);
               j = j/10;
            }`

Another mistake was you were not using the equality in the if statement, instead you were assigning values to the variables.
The correct code would be as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CreditCardVerification
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String cardNum;
        String typeAnswer;
        char cardType;
        int testSum=0;
        int r;
        int modResult;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("\t\t Credit Card Verification");
        System.out.println("\t\t ========================");
        System.out.println("Enter your card number <xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx>: ");
        cardNum = scan.nextLine();
        if(cardNum.length()<19 || cardNum.length()>19)
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect card number. Re-launch the program  and enter a 16-digit card number");
            System.exit(0);
         }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Is your card Visa or MasterCard?");
            typeAnswer = scan.next().toUpperCase();
            cardType = typeAnswer.charAt(0);                
            String numSet1 = cardNum.substring(0,4);
            String numSet2 = cardNum.substring(5,9);
            String numSet3 = cardNum.substring(10,14);
            String numSet4 = cardNum.substring(15,19);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(numSet1);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(numSet2);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(numSet3);
            int l = Integer.parseInt(numSet4);
            int sum1=0;
            while(i!=0)
            {
                sum1 = sum1 + (i%10);
                i = i/10;
            }
            int sum2 = 0;
            while(j!=0)
            {
                sum2 = sum2 + (j%10);
                j = j/10;
            }
            int sum3 = 0;
            while(k!=0)
            {
                sum3 = sum3+ (k%10);
                k = k/10;
            } 
            int sum4 = 0;
            while(l!=0)
            {
               sum4 = sum4 + (l%10);
               l = l/10;
            }
            testSum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4;
            modResult = testSum%10;                    
            if((modResult==0) && (cardType=='V'))
            {
                System.out.println("Valid Visa card.");              
            }
            else if ((modResult==1) && (cardType=='M'))
            {
                System.out.println("Valid MasterCard.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not a valid " + typeAnswer + " card. Re-launch and try again.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Try this code.Its not so different from the code given by MikeCat but this should solve your problem. Take caution that don't enter just any number and test the code. Try it with a valid Visa or MasterCard credit card.